# Show SVG Preview Pane in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

Tags: user-interface, svg, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Web Essentials 2015 on it, and I used to get a preview pane any time I highlighted a SVG in the solution explorer. For whatever reasons for the past week it doesn't seem to do that anymore.

I've already gone into Tools > Options > Web Essentials > General and set Show preview pane to true. I also uninstalled and reinstalled Web Essentials, but still no dice.

Any idea how to get the SVG preview pane back? Or is this somehow tied to the typescript preview pane being removed thanks to the most recent Visual Studio update?

Comment: I should add that the preview I'm looking for is a graphical preview, not just the code preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an [issue on github](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/203) this is fixed in the latest build.

[Download and install the latest build from here](http://vsixgallery.com/extension/5fb7364d-2e8c-44a4-95eb-2a382e30fec9/).

Answer (score 2):

After much searching, it would appear this is no longer available. I have not found a worthwhile replacement, either.